# How to install ctag on a computer with no admin rights?

Tags: ctags

I have a Scientific Linux 6 machine in my office which I do not have admin rights to but work from. I would like to use Ctags using vim there. However how can I install this if I do not have admin rights? Is there anything similar I use or maybe a plugin?

cheers,
Alex.